# How to display the result automatically in EditText?

Tags: java, android, currency

I am developing an application for converting values ​​from kW to km, I would like to see the score in EditText2 when I entered the value in EditText1 without using any button to do this automatically in the view, but I have no idea how to do this. Right now I must have to select the right value from Spinner to get the result in EditText2. How can this change? Maybe in the wrong way I'm looking for a search value from the Spinner? I will also ask you how to improve the application. Thank you.

I try use TextWeatcher, but still it's not working.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {


    Spinner spinner1, spinner2;
    EditText editText1, editText2;
    double count = 1.36;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

        editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                String c = s.toString();
                editText2.setText(c);
            }
        });

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.przelicznik_arrayKM,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.przelicznik_arraykW,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);

        spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) parent;
        String text = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();

        String text2 = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();


        if(text.equals("kW") & text2.equals("KM") ) {

            try {
                double a = Double.parseDouble(editText1.getText().toString());
                double suma = a / count;

                editText2.setText(String.valueOf(suma));

            }catch (NumberFormatException e){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Enter yout value!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

        if(text.equals("KM") & text2.equals("kW")){

             try {
                 double a = Double.parseDouble(editText1.getText().toString());
                 double suma = a /count;

                 editText2.setText(String.valueOf(suma));

             }catch (NumberFormatException e){
                 Toast.makeText(this, "Enter your value!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
         } else {
            String textString = editText1.getText().toString();
            editText2.setText(String.valueOf(textString));
          }
        }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}

    public void clearEditText(View view) {

        editText1.setText("");
        editText2.setText("");
    }
}
```

Strings.xml

```
    <resources>
    <string name="app_name">PrzelicznikMocySilnika</string>

    <string-array name="przelicznik_arraykW">
        <item>kW</item>
        <item>KM</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="przelicznik_arrayKM">
        <item>KM</item>
        <item>kW</item>
    </string-array>



</resources>
```

Layout.xmln

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.hfad.przelicznikmocysilnika.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:hint="Enter your value"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/spinner1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:hint="Enter your value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/spinner2" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText2" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="Reset"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:onClick="clearEditText"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You can update the `EditText2` in `runable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For two-way conversion between two EditText views, you have to do conversion only when edittext is on focus. The sample code is below.

```
editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                if (editText1.isFocused()) {
                    String str = editText1.getText().toString().trim();
                    if (!str.isEmpty()) {
                        //your conversion logic here
                        editText2.setText(String.valueOf(convertedValue));
                    }else{
                        etTo.setText("0");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Try also similar approach for conversion from editText2 to editText1.

Comment: Your code works!  
This is what I was looking for. Thank you :)

Comment: Glad to know @newActivity21

Answer (score 1):

Perform your operations in the `onTextChanged` method

To get the current value use `editText1.getText().toString()`

Comment: You're right. However, I still have trouble adding the onItemSelected method to the onTextChanged to immediately show the result in EditText2. Because it now only shows the value entered in EditText1, but it does not show
the result immediately.

Comment: Perform the conversion after text changed now. The same code in the onItemSelected for conversion should be added to the `onTextChanged` method

Answer (score 0):

add your logic in onTextChanged instead of afterTextChanged

```
editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            String c = editText1.getText().toString();
            editText2.setText(c);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a listener for text changes.

```
your_edittext.addTextChangedListener(new InputValidator());

private class InputValidator implements TextWatcher {

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }    
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {                

    }    
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {

    }    
}
```

}

Comment: This is what the user is trying to do that isn't working.